# Dynamic MaterialDesign PackIconKind from config XML in WPF application

Tags: c#, wpf, material-design-icons

I am designing one WPF desktop application where the UI design is totally driven by an configuration file. I have MenuItems which uses MaterialDesign PackIcons. I have the PackIcons mentioned in the config file for each menuitem. e.g.

```
<MenuItem Name="Menu1">
    ....
    <Icon Type="MaterialDesign">NewBox</Icon>
</MenuItem>
<MenuItem Name="Menu2">
    ....
    <Icon Type="MaterialDesign">ExitToApp</Icon>
</MenuItem>
```

Now I want to use this icon names while desiging the MenuItems. In XAML I know how to do this

```html
<MenuItem Header="New" Click="MenuItem_NewClick" >
    <MenuItem.Icon>
        <materialDesign:PackIcon Kind="NewBox" />
    </MenuItem.Icon>
</MenuItem>
```

But I am facing challenge when I am trying to do it via code behind. Normally, we can do this by the following line of code if we have the icon fixed

```
MenuItem.Icon = new MaterialDesignThemes.Wpf.PackIcon { Kind = MaterialDesignThemes.Wpf.PackIconKind.NewBox};
```

Can somebody please help me by telling how can I use dynamic icon via code behind?

Thanks

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do in the code-behind? What's the difference between your case and the "normal" case that you have describe above?

Comment: I want to make the PackIconKind dynamic. I want to replace the below line with dynamic code.

Kind = MaterialDesignThemes.Wpf.PackIconKind.NewBox.

Because I don't know whether it is "NewBox" or something else. It comes from configuration

Comment: So where do you get the `Kind` from then?

Comment: From my configuration file. For every menuitem it is mentioned.

Comment: How do you parse the config file?

Comment: I have xml parser written for that. All information is stored in an object

Comment: So it gives you a string with a value of for example "NewBox" that you wan to convert into a `Pack`? Or what is your actual question?

Comment: yes. You are correct. I want to convert my string value to Pack.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `Enum.Parse` or `Enum.TryParse` method to convert a `string` value to a `PackIconKind`, e.g.:

```
var kind = (MaterialDesignThemes.Wpf.PackIconKind)Enum
    .Parse(typeof(MaterialDesignThemes.Wpf.PackIconKind), "About");
```